# read 1450000 line of yelp review json file and more line with R

Tags: r, bigdata, yelp

I use below code for reading review json file. recently I have a problem for reading 1450000 and more lines...my computer cant read after 6 hours!
what is the solution?

```
setwd("d:/yelp_dataset")
rm(list=ls())
library(jsonlite)
rev<- 'd:/yelp_dataset/review.JSON'
revu<-jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(readLines(rev, n=1450000)),verbose=F)
```

Comment: setwd("d:/yelp_dataset")
rm(list=ls())
library(jsonlite)
rev<- 'd:/yelp_dataset/review.JSON'
revu<-jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(readLines(rev, n=1450000)),verbose=F)

Comment: How to ask a great SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?answertab=votes#tab-top